# Dividing an array of ids sent by GET method into seperate ids Dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, get

i have an array containing several ids sent by GET method, and i want to get each id by a variable , my code was fixed for 2 ids only and i retrieved them using the following code :

```
$searchString = ',';

if( strpos($_GET['id'], $searchString) != false ) 
{   
    $claimID = explode( ',', $_GET['id'] );
    $claimID1=$claimID[0];
    $claimID2=$claimID[1];
}
```

Now after a change, is it possible to get more than 2 ids, unlimited, and i want to retrieve them all and use them in queries and layouts, how could i achieve this ? i have to use a loop when exploding and whenever i want to do an operation on all the ids ( query for each id ) i have to loop ?

[image]

Ok so i used to explode on , and get the 2 values in 2 different parameters and do 2 queries to get amounts and add them together into 1 amount, and then use an update query for each id, my objective is still the same but for 2+ ids, note that in User No. it takes the 3 values sent but concatinated by commas for now

Comment: What is wrong with just having all the values in the $claimID array? And, yes, to operate on all elements of this array you would loop through them.

Comment: @AndyG i have to use each id in the query, and then send the ids with ajax call, i have hidden inputs with the 2 values retrieved from get

Comment: "it's possible to get more than 2 ids, unlimited, and i want to retrieve them all " if you don't know how many id's you might have then an array remains the best option (the two answers provided also come with disclaimers).

Comment: @AndyG true, i might have from 1 up to 10+

Comment: @AndyG i will post an image for more info. and to be able to understand my goal

Answer (score 0):

You can actually dynamically name variables, altough its not recommended:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 5];
$i = 1;
foreach($arr as $val) {
    $name = "claimID" . $i++;
    $$name = $val;
}
// Outputs 5
echo $claimID3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create variable variables in PHP but I would not use and do that. Keeping everything in an array is much more easier.

Infos on variable variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php
(This is untested and as I said, I wouldn't do it).

```
if( strpos($_GET['id'], $searchString) != false ) {

  $claimID = explode( ',', $_GET['id'] );
  for($i=0;$i<count($claimID);$i++) {
    $varname = 'claimID' . $i;
    $$varname = $claimID[$i];
  }
}
```